# Github login best way from CLI / Git Bash

Tags: github

Ever since Github changed it's policy to not accept username/password anymore, I'm having a difficult time logging in when I push a branch to the remote repo.

I've tried a PKA key, but I forget it sometimes and I have to regenerate. Then I stored it in a plain text file and copy-paste when needed. And this PKA key seems like an API key for one project, instead of a way to log in manually to push changes. This seems to me like not-the-way to go. And I can imagine professionals do this in a better way.

I'm using a Linux machine and git from the terminal. And a Windows 10 machine with Git Bash (Git for Windows). How should I configure my account and computers so that I can easily run `git push origin master`?

Is it possible to use 2FA in a way where I log in with my account username and password and verify my login with an authenticator app on my phone? And preferably trust my computer from future logins.

Comment: Add your ssh keys to GitHub and use ssh repo link.

Comment: @Rahul does that work per machine or per repo? I'd prefer a machine wide solution as I have 10+ repo's that I manage from 2 machines.

Comment: well, ssh keys are machine specific so you can add your public ssh keys of both the machines to Github. That will do.

Comment: use this https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to store your credentials globally on your machine. Store your credentials in global git configuration file.

WARNING: Your credentials would be visible to everyone who uses your machine, but the config file is usually hidden `/.config`.

**Store your credentials on your machine globally:**

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Next time you enter your credentials, this will store your credentials. In next consequent times, you won't be prompt to enter credentials anymore.

Comment: And what do I supply as the "password" of the credentials?

Comment: @arjobsen Your GitHub user password.

Comment: It says "Fatal: AggregationError" and "remote: Invalid username or password." 
My regular username/password combination stopped working on the CLI when I set up 2FA on github.com. I thought that logging in requires a token instead of a password

Comment: 2FA https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/57#issuecomment-174156276

Comment: This seems like a totally unrelated problem. I can ping api.github.com

Comment: That complete issue has many Fatal: AggregationError instances, I'm sure your problem is already in the comments there e.g. SET GCM_VALIDATE=false setting variable.